# How to stop a repeating error message or figure out where it is coming from

Tags: python

I am working with some python code, which is quite complex (for me at least). There are many objects and modules and functions that call other functions etc.

When I run the code, **sometimes** something goes wrong. (It makes sense that it doesn't always go wrong, because it involves sampling and random number etc..)

When the code goes wrong, it doesn't crash, but I'm getting an output repeated ad infinitum (it may stop if I left it long enough):

```
Diagonal element of covariance matrix = 0
Diagonal element of covariance matrix = 0
Diagonal element of covariance matrix = 0
.
.
```

I can't seem to figure out which of the many imported modules is producing this message. I'm not even sure at what point in the code this is happening because any other output is lost from the screen. I don't want to read all output into a text file, because the code runs a long time before it does or doesn't fail and the file will be very large I guess.

Is there any way that I can get my code to break as soon as it starts spitting out this `Diagonal element of covariance matrix = 0` message. Then I could at least figure out where in the code the problem is occuring.

Any other ideas welcome too!

Comment: If you are unable to search the code for the line responsible for that warning print out, then I recommend using an ide (pycharm) and run the code in debugger mode, hit pause once the warning starts to print out.

Comment: if it's a cli, try using `python -m trace ...` :https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html

Answer (score 1):

While I am not happy to say it, your best bet may be using some kind of timer to kill the function's execution. For example, you could put something like this in your code to kill the function and then attempt to either generate a new random matrix, or attempt to fix the covariance matrix manually.

```
import time
import signal


def black_box():
    while True:
        print("Diagonal element of covariance matrix = 0")


def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise Exception("Timed out!")


signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
signal.alarm(5) # Upper bound of execution normal time
try:
    black_box()
except Exception:
    # Handle timeout
    pass

signal.pause()
```

Best of luck...

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain a little about what this code is doing please?

Comment: @user1551817 Definitely! It is essentially the python equivalent of a [Watchdog Timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer). These timers are super common in hardware. Essentially, if the timer is not reset due to abnormally long execution, it is treated as an error. Therefore, you can handle it differently than the normal execution, and do something else or reset.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure why the black_box function is printing the line "Diagonal element of covariance matrix = 0". This is the line that prints over and over anyway. Sorry if I'm missing the point.

Comment: @user1551817 This methodology isn't very common in non-hardware interfacing code, because it is usually debug-able. Compared to a device operating in an environment, where it is general not feasible or practical to debug.

Comment: @user1551817 I just just put that in the example as an illustration of how it works just in case you wanted to test the code before merging it into your code base. As you can see when the example is run it would normally never exit unless killed. But given the signal stuff it will finish after ~5 seconds.

Comment: But do I put the rest of my code in the black_box function? How will the signal know that an exception has occurred when the code starts spitting out "Diagonal element..."? The code is still technically running. I'm sorry I don't understand. I thought the signal does something when the code has stopped running for 5 seconds.

Comment: @user1551817 You can just put the code that is causing issues in the try part of the try-catch block. the black_box function I created was just to illustrate the problem you were having since in theory the function example I gave spits out that message and never exits.  The error is thrown when the signal is timer has not been reset or paused within the five second time frame. It is completely independent of your code. Given that your code blocks the program occasionally for a significant period of time, thus not getting to the `signal.pause()` line, the error will be thrown. Killing the code.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Sorry I was completely misunderstanding something. Thank you!

Comment: @user1551817 Its all good. Signals are a weird thing. I also made [a gif](https://imgur.com/a/KtEHsxk) of this in action with some added inline explanation to better show how it works.

Comment: That's very helpful thank you. I have definitely learned something. The problem, however, is that my code takes a few minutes to run though even when it's working correctly. So the signal thing is stopping it after 5 seconds anyway. Of course I can set the signal time to be much longer - but that defeats the purpose of trying to kill the code as soon as possible after it starts to output "Diagonal element..."

Comment: @user1551817 The only way you can immediately do that is debug the existing code. Or finding where that is printed out at inserting this in there. Possibly shortening the lead time.

Comment: @user1551817 And with this approach you can handle it without manually restarting the code yourself, which accounts for something.